# How does React hook useRef() work under the hood? What is that reference exactly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been dealing with some problems with the React hook useRef(), and I guess this is because I haven't still really grasped the concept and functionality of it.

I know it can be used as a 'global' variable which lives outside of the function's scope. So the following counter works just fine. I just needed to force update it, because changing the `myCounter.current` property doesn't trigger a rerender by itself.

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function App() {

  const myCounter = useRef(0);
  const [forceUpdate,setForceUpdate] = useState(true);
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    myCounter.current+=1;
    setForceUpdate((prev)=>!prev);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{myCounter.current}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

My doubt begins when I use it to store a reference of an HTML element. From the React Docs below, we know that will be getting the same object on every render. So I'm getting the same reference of the html element on every render (as long as it keeps mounted, at least).

[From React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

> This works because useRef() **creates a plain JavaScript object.** The
>   only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object
>   yourself is that **useRef will give you the same ref object on every
>   render.**

For example:

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function App() {

  const myDivElement = useRef(null);
  
  const [forceUpdate,setForceUpdate] = useState(true);
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (myDivElement.current.style.color === 'red') {
      myDivElement.current.style.color='black';  
    }
    else {
      myDivElement.current.style.color='red';
    }
    setForceUpdate((prev)=>!prev);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={myDivElement}><b>Some content inside my Div element</b></div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Note: I know it's not the best practice to have multiple questions inside here. But this one is more of a conceptual kind and understanding the following items would really help me to fully grasp the functionality of this hook.

**Item 1**

What does the reference `myDivElement.current` points to exactly? Does it point to the node object of that element inside the virtual DOM? Because I know that when I change a CSS property of it, for example, I see that change reflected on the DOM as we can see from the snippet above.

**Item 2**

Can I say that what I get in `myDivElement.current` object is one of the type [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) (MDN link) ? If not, what kind/type of object is it?

**Item 3**

`myDivElement.current` is being initialized with `null` value. When does that change to the reference of the `div`? Does it happen after 1st render?

**EXTRA EDIT:**

I made this extra snippet to show some clarifying React behavior in comparing DOM nodes that were modified by `ref` access.

- The first button uses `ref` to modify the DOM directly (toggle red and black color), hence you see a color change without a new render.
- When you Force Blue through a change in `state` and return it as inline attribute as return of the render, you imediately see that it triggers a re-render (cause it changes the blue state) and you see the color blue.
- But the strange thing is that when you click again the 1st button to change the color through `ref` it goes red/black again, but now you can't get it back to blue even if you Force Update it. It will re-render but not update the DOM.
- Since the blue `state` has become `true`, react compares the result of the render with the one in the virtual DOM (which has been blue since you clicked Force Blue for the 1st time) and comes back as equal nodes. It doesn't know that the DOM is actually red, because you've altered directly through `ref`.

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function App() {

  const myDivElement = useRef(null);
  
  const [blue,setBlue] = useState(false);
  
  const [forceUpdate,setForceUpdate] = useState(true);
  
  const renderTimes = useRef(0);
  
  renderTimes.current+=1;
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (myDivElement.current.style.color === 'red') {
      myDivElement.current.style.color='black';  
    }
    else {
      myDivElement.current.style.color='red';
    }
    //setForceUpdate((prev)=>!prev);
    //setBlue(false);
  }
  
  const handleClick2 = (e) => {
    setForceUpdate((prev)=>!prev);
    // setBlue(false);
  }
  
  const handleClick3 = (e) => {
    setBlue(true);
  }

  const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={myDivElement} style={{ color: blue? 'blue' : 'initial'}}><b>Some content inside my Div element</b></div>
      <p>I was rendered {renderTimes.current} time(s)</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Toggle Color with useRef()</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>Force Update</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick3}>Force Blue as inline style</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the reference `myDivElement.current` points to exactly

`myDivElement.current` receives the reference to the underlying DOM element

> Can I say that what I get in `myDivElement.current` object is one of the
>   type HTMLElement

When you assign ref to a div element, `myDivElement.current` will be of type [HTMLDivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement)

> `myDivElement.current` is being initialized with null value. When does
>   that change to the reference of the div? Does it happen after 1st
>   render?

During first render, the ref object is being assigned to the DOMNode when its created. Updates to DOM node will lead to a change in the object as well

Comment: " **myDivElement.current receives the reference to the underlying DOM element**"

What do you mean by that exactly? The actual DOM ? Is it like bypassing the Virtual DOM? Shouldn't I get a reference to the VDOM ? If I am getting a reference to the DOM itself, I'm changing it and React is updating the VDOM based on that change? Shouldn't it be the other way around? Like, our code leading to changes into the VDOM and React updating the DOM based on that? Thanks.

Comment: ref holds reference to actual DOM and not virtual DOM, also the changes that you do via ref are related directly to DOM manipulation. Also most times you only need to access certain attributes from DOM for which you use ref. Setting state or updating styles should be done via css classes or though via style prop in JSX

Comment: But doest that mean that the VDOM will be different from the DOM itself? Like my `div` node into the VDOM won't have the inline style `color: 'red'` and the actual DOM will have it? How does React handle that decoupling the next time it renders? Wouldn't it be replaced by the content of the VDOM? Thanks again!

Comment: VDOM is different from DOM and is minimal version of the DOM. And react don't replace the original dom with Virtual DOM instead just makes update changes